# User Profile Manager and its Enum does not give me the same count

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, powershell, user-profile

Today, I have encountered another issue with SharePoint 2010. I have a powershell script that can pull the user profile details from the User Profile store, having used `UserProfileManager` to get the user profile details its shows the profile count as 75000 however if I enumerate the same object it gives me only 74600 user profiles. I have even tried with foreach and while loop to iterate the enum object howver the end result is same.

How the `UserProfileManager` Object shows the count as 75000 and the same object gives only 74600 profiles if I enumerate?

Are those 400 profiles are invalid? Even if those are invalid, it should say atleast those are invalid or null, am I right?

**Update:**

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://mysiteurl"
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site


$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext)
$userProfiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator();

$UserCount = 1;

while($userProfiles.MoveNext()) {
$usrprofile = $userProfiles.Current;
$UserCount++ | out-file "E:\Temp\USP.txt" -append
$usrprofile["AccountName"]| out-file "E:\Temp\USP.txt" -append
}
```

`$profileManager.Count` gives 75000 however I could see only 74600 entries in the log file *"D:\Temp\USP.txt"*

What could be the issue? Even, I have verified the profile missed from import and it does not have more than few entries.

Any suggestions?

Update-2:
The same code works perfectly in the QA environment.
We have configured the UPRE sync in the production, would that be an issue?

Comment: by the way user profile service says 75000.

Comment: When you compare the actual differences what is different about the accounts? You mention the UPRE. Are the accounts from a different domain rather than your sync source? Are the accounts marked "missing from import"?

Comment: I have reprovisioned the Sync DB and it solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
# List all user accounts that is not imported correctly (no email)
Get-SPServiceApplication
$upsa = Get-SPServiceApplication –Identity ID
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upsa -GetNonImportedObjects $true
```

***or***

Run the following jobs to delete My Sites and corresponding User Profiles

- Dead Site Delete
- My Site Cleanup Job